# How to center a draggable item on droppable image-map area using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have HTML file with image, its image-map and one draggable item (*div* element). I have also jQuery file in which I made an image/image-map droppable and an item draggable. So, when I drag the item over the image-map (droppable) area, area is highlighted and I can normally do some code (made with .mapster() - http://blog.outsharked.com/2012/02/dragging-and-dropping-onto-html-image.html ). And so, **my question is can I position that dragged item in the center of an image-map area**, not the image, the image-map area. It looks ugly the way it's now, it just dragged and so messy when there's couple more items on image. It's about roulette, so it needs to be centred and nice to see. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red;" class="ui-widget-header">

        <div id="container">
            <img id="mainSectorBet" class="mainSectorBet" src="http://localhost:5500/slike/mainSectorBet.png" usemap="#image-map">
    
            <map name="image-map" id="my-image-map">
                <area id="nula" target="" alt="P0" title="P0" href="" coords="82,230,82,1,45,17,10,71,1,117,12,166,45,213" shape="poly">
                <area id="C1" target="" alt="C1" title="C1" href="" coords="151,142,177,164" shape="rect">
            </map>    
        </div>

        
        <div id="draggable" class="divar">

        </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( function () {
    $('#mainSectorBet').mapster({
        mapKey: "alt",
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        fillColor: 'ff0000',
        stroke: true,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeColor: '00ff00',
        onConfigured: function() {
            $('#mainSectorBet').siblings().css('z-index', 0);
            $('#mainSectorBet').css('z-index', 10);
        }
    }).parent().css({"display":"flex", "justify-content":"center", "align-items": "center"});

    $(".divar" ).css('z-index', 5).draggable({
        opacity: "0.5",
        cursor: "grabbing",
        revert: 'invalid',
        drag: function(){
            $(this).css('z-index', 5)
        }
    });

    $("#mainSectorBet").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var landing = $('#mainSectorBet').mapster('highlight');
            //$(ui.draggable).css('z-index', 20);

            if(landing){
                alert("Landing: " + landing);
            }            
        }
    });
})
```

**Picture of it:**

[Roulette image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVw2i.png)

So I want to center that blue square (on drag 'n drop) inside the green "0" area. Hope it's possible!

*Sorry for some English grammar mistakes*

**THANKS TO ALL IN ADVANCE!**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Addressing your question, *...can I position that dragged item in the center of an image-map area...* the answer is yes. The how is more difficult. Please review: https://jqueryui.com/position/

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function animate(to) {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate(to);
  }

  $(".divar").css('z-index', 5).draggable({
    opacity: "0.5",
    cursor: "grabbing",
    revert: 'invalid',
    drag: function() {
      $(this).css('z-index', 5)
    }
  });

  $("#container").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $drag = ui.draggable;
      if (ui.position.left < 200) {
        event.pageX = $(this).position().left + 100;
        event.pageY = $(this).position().top + 225;
      }
      $drag.position({
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: event,
        using: animate
      });
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.whiteText {
  font: 50px sans-serif;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div style="border: 1px solid red;" class="ui-widget-header">
  <div id="container">
    <svg width="1000" height="450" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <ellipse ry="225" rx="200" cy="225" cx="200" stroke="#000" fill="green"/>
      <rect height="450" width="800" y="0" x="200" stroke="#000" fill="red"/>
      <text x="100" y="250" class="whiteText">0</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="draggable" class="divar">
  </div>
</div>
```

I used an SVG as I cannot replicate the example with your Image. You might consider using SVG instead of an Image Map.

When they item is dropped, you can check it's position and move it using `.position()`. See Demo:  https://jqueryui.com/position/#cycler

In this case, I knew the that if it was within 200 px from the image edge, it was in the ellipse area (or 0 section). Then it's just a matter of calculating the position and centering the element in that position.

See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/position/